# extract subsection between two dates in an R dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to extract a range of data from a dataframe between two specific date times; such as extracting the CFS(velocity)of a river between two dates. I've scoured through my stack of R books and all over the web and have found a few possible answers but do not work for my particular application.

I would assume that this should be a fairly straightforward task to achieve in R. I can perform it in my sleep using MySQl but need to perform it in R.

Format of the data frame:

Date,  CFS,   Temp,

2015-06-01 00:00, 2009, 12.5

2015-06-01 00:30, 2010, 12.5

`data <- read.table("~/SomeObscureDataDirectory/RiverDataFull", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
sub1 <- subset(data, data$Date >= 2015-06-01 00:00 & data$Date <= 2015-06-01 07:15)`

//---------------->

```
> data <- read.table("~/SomeObscureDataDirectory", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
> sub1 <- subset(data, data$Date >= 2015-06-01 00:00 & data$Date <=2015-06-01 07:15)
    Error: unexpected numeric constant in "sub1 <- subset(data, data$Date >= 2015-06-01 00"
```

I'm at a loss for a solution, your expertise would be greatly appreciated. I'm assuming that the date format is not allowing me to search against it? Note: I cannot change the format in the RiverDataFull.tab file it resides in.

Comment: What is the `class` of the date column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `date` column of your data frame is a factor.  Therefore you will need to convert this column to a date type and make your comparisons against another date type.  You can use the `as.POSIXct()` function to do this:

```
data$Date <- as.POSIXct(data$Date, format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M');    # convert to date
sub1 <- subset(data, data$Date >= as.POSIXct("2015-06-01 00:00") &
               data$Date <= as.POSIXct("2015-06-01 07:15"))
```

In your original code you were trying to use raw numbers and strings and this won't work.

Comment: Thank you. I figured I overlooked the obvious. I will test this and reply.

Comment: I get another error but Im sure I can solve this one. If you have suggestions, please feel free to chime in. Im a noob in R.
`Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.POSIXt") for ">="
2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.POSIXt") for "<="`

Comment: @JohnP.Newbury I updated my answer.  From your error it appears that your `Date` column is a factor.  You will need to convert that to a date type before doing the comparison.

Comment: I discovered the same thing regarding Date type conversion. I will mark as answered as soon as I validate this. thank you.

Comment: I no longer get errors but it is returning empty rows.

`[1] Date CFS  Temp
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Its an import error.